# Django : Filtering Post by user + UserProfile data

Tags: python, django

I hope you're well. I got an error: `name 'username' is not defined`
I'd like to have a public page with the user slug.

Ex. profile/louis/
Louis's Post + Louis's UserProfileData

I'm beginning with Django, so I made some mistake.

nutriscore/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
```

user/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

user/views.py

```
#public profile        
@login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def userpublicpostview(request, slug):
    template = 'user_public_profile.html'
    user = User.objects.filter(username).values()
    user_id = user[0]['id'] 
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=userprofile).values()  
    user_post = Post.objects.filter(author = user_id, slug=slug) 
    return render(request, template, {'user_posts':user_posts,'userpublic': userpublic})
```

user/urls.py

```
path('profile/<slug:slug>/', userpublicpostview,name="user_public_cookwall"),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code :

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def userpublicpostview(request, slug):
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects.select_related('userprofile'), username=slug)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author_id=user.id) 
    return render(request, 'user_public_profile.html', {
        'user_posts': posts,
        'userpublic': user.userprofile
    })
```

And in your html, display posts this way :

```html
{% for post in user_posts %}
    <a href=‘{% url ‘user:user_public_cookwall’ post.author.slug %}’>{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but I got this:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: Thanks a lot bro you helped me a lot :) could you tell what balise I need to use to display post on user_public_profile.html?

Comment: If I want to display the link of a user profile. For exemple, from a post (author part:  {{ post.author }} ). I'm using this in a link 
{% url 'user:user_public_cookwall' %} but something wrong... 

Reverse for 'user_public_cookwall' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['earlycooker/profile/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: cool for this code works: {% url 'user:user_public_cookwall' slug=post.author.userprofile.slug %}

Answer (score 1):

Use these lines:

```
user = User.objects.filter(username=slug).values()
...
userprofile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).values()  
user_post = Post.objects.filter(author = user_id)  # removed slug from here
...
return render(request, template, {'user_posts':user_posts,'userpublic': userprofile})
```

### An efficient version

#### view

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required(login_url='/earlycooker/login')
def userpublicpostview(request, slug):
    template = 'user_public_profile.html'
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects.prefetch_related('blog_posts'), username=slug)
    return render(request, template, {'current_user':user})
```

#### template

```
# user profile information

{{ current_user.userprofile.bio }}
{{ current_user.userprofile.profile_pic }}

# posts

{% for post in current_user.post_set.all %}
  {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

You can see here that I can access Profile information via `current_user.userprofile` because of [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) relation between `User` model and `UserProfile` model in template. Secondly, I can access all the posts of a given user by makeing reverse query `current_user.post_set.all` and iterate through the posts. More information on reverse relation(related objects) can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: thanks ruddra apparently I made another mistake about UserProfile: local variable 'userprofile' referenced before assignment

Comment: I have updated the answer, but I am not sure is this what you meant to achieve

Comment: I'd like to have the slug for the user :) profile/<slug:slug>/' like profile/louis/ or profile/fredo/

Comment: User slug + display data from UserProfile:
Ex. profile/louis/
I want to display Louis's Post and Louis UserProfile Data
Ex profile/fredo/
I want to display Fredo's Post and Fredo UserProfile Data

Comment: I think you can reduce the code a lot. I have added an efficient implementation of the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro you helped me a lot :)

Comment: Thanks for taking time to explain me the answer